# HTML vs SHTML vs PHTML

Tags: html, php, shtml

What is the **difference** between:

```
HTML
SHTML
PHTML
```

**Why** and **when** i'll use **which** one?

Comment: Could you add some links to point to what you're referring to? HTML is clear enough, but SHTML and PHTML may need further clarification so we know what you're talking about.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like [SHTML](http://www.kennesaw.edu/webmaster/whatis/shtml.html) = Server Side include HTML (SSI), which is just a fancy way of saying the server can dynamically inject code at the reference point (i.e. where the include is).

[PHTML](http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/definition/phtml-suffix) is HTML code with inline PHP processing instructions.

Comment: PHTML is not an encoding method. That link is a PHTML encoder. That means it __encodes PHTML__. PHTML is just another way to say HTML code with inline PHP processing instructions.

Comment: wait then what's the difference between phtml and plain php?

Answer (score 8):

Use static HTML when you want to have static content. Use SHTML if you want to do simple things such as [includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes). Use PHTML if you want to use logic (though it's possible to do with SHTML if you really want to).

Answer (score 0):

**.phtml** is usual extension to Phalcom PHP Framework files :)
Ref.: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tutorial.html

Comment: **.phtml** was the standard file extension for PHP 2 programs and is still used in some rare cases
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11859015/what-is-phtml-and-when-should-i-use-a-phtml-extension-rather-than-php/11859122