# Run PHP in HTML page

Tags: php, html

I am trying to run PHP in HTML page.

I saved this file in WAMP as a `.html`

```
<html>
  <body>
    <?php echo "My first PHP script!";?>
  </body>
</html>
```

But when I open it with the browser and I do inspect element the result is this:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <!--?php
            echo "My first PHP script!";
        ?--> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: delete your file, and won't show it :)) or just rename to .php :))

Comment: Hahaha, it works ok. Thank you. It's my first php, I wanted to test...

Comment: @Downvoters - Why down vote this question? Sure, it's simple but it's well structured and on topic.

Comment: I haven't down-voted, but I will try to "fix" one down-vote, although doesn't worth neither up-vote, so +1 from me.

Comment: Only Chuck Norris can run php in html file.

Comment: @slavoo - Him and John Skeet! ;)

Answer (score 4):

If Apache is not running `.html` pages as php scripts then running a `.html` page won't run as `.php`

Answer (score 2):

Solution: Rename your filename from `something.html` to `something.php`

or alternatively `something.phtml` although this is uncommon

Answer (score 1):

You can also save the page as `.phtml`. This format is possible of displaying `.php` & `.html`.

Take a look here for more information: [What is phtml, and when should I use a .phtml extension rather than .php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11859015/what-is-phtml-and-when-should-i-use-a-phtml-extension-rather-than-php)

Comment: Take a look here for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11859015/what-is-phtml-and-when-should-i-use-a-phtml-extension-rather-than-php

Comment: Best to add that information against your answer for clarity :)

Comment: I will do that the next time, thq you @webnoob

Answer (score 0):

You should save it as `.php` instead of `.html`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put it into a `.php` file, the webserver (if not configured so) won't interpret `.html` files as PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Like others said, by changing file extension from .html to .php would work. However, if you don't want to do that, you may want to check [this](http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/p/html_php.htm) out. It allows you to execute php file without change file extension.