# Is there specific name of php with HTML?

Tags: java, php

Like Java and JSP, is there name for pure PHP and PHP inside of HTML?

I'm looking for information about PHP with HTML, and I want to filter off pure PHP information.

Comment: Have you tried "embedded PHP"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an unofficial term, called PHTML. Some programmers tend to use the *.phtml file name extension for a number of reasons.

It's briefly described here:
[What is phtml, and when should I use a .phtml extension rather than .php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11859015/what-is-phtml-and-when-should-i-use-a-phtml-extension-rather-than-php)