# PHP: default value while a variable is not set?

Tags: php, variables, undefined, declaration

I have a code that searches **tags** in *.html* file but I have problem executing the script it leads me to undefined index.

on my previous [QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19844082/php-php-and-html-file-separation) I ask about searching **id tags** and I't leads me to used it as a reference. Enhancing the code and executing the code correctly but it shows me an error. The error searches every *id tags* in a **.html file**

CODE:

```
<?php
function getElementById($matches)
{
    global $data;
    return $matches[1].$matches[3].$matches[4].$data[$matches[3]].$matches[6];
}

$data['test'] = 'A';

$filename = 'test.html';

$html = file_exists($filename) ? file_get_contents($filename) : die('can\'t open the file');

$_HTML = preg_replace_callback('#(<([a-zA-Z]+)[^>]*id=")(.*?)("[^>]*>)([^<]*?)(</\\2>)#ism', 'getElementById', $html);

echo $_HTML;
?>
```

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TEST</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="test"></div>
        <div id="test2"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

OUTPUT: [PRINTSCREEN](http://prntscr.com/22ltov)

Comment: [You can't parse HTML with regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/156811).

Comment: Seems the code *that was written for you* is working ok. You just didn't define `test2` in your `$data` array.

Comment: I don't get it, do you not understand the error message? Seems pretty clear, but I don't understand why you are doing this. If you actually want to do this (and you probably don't, see the other comments/answers), you could _at least_ use `isset()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can implement a default:

```
$data3 = isset($data[$matches[3]]) ? $data[$matches[3]] : 'default';
return $matches[1].$matches[3].$matches[4].$data3.$matches[6];
```

Answer (score 1):

***Disclaimer: You shouldn't be doing all this regex stuff with HTML, blah, blah...***

But if you insist

```
function getElementById($matches)
{
    global $data;
    return $matches[1]
        .$matches[3]
        .$matches[4]
        .isset($data[$matches[3]]) ? $data[$matches[3]] : 'DEFAULT_VALUE'
        .$matches[6];
}
```

Why not use regex?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/156811

[Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

I'm sure you can find more if you do a quick search

Some alternatives:

https://www.php.net/dom

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

etc.

Comment: whay there's a disadvantage using regex on html?

Comment: Have you even been reading the responses here? The first link in the comments on your question is probably a good starting point. HTML is context free, not regular, so it can't be done in a general case. For a specific small case (e.g. you have **well known** HTML that you create yourself that will always follow certain rules and you need to get something small out of it), then maybe regex makes some sense.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is not really the correct way todo this. I suggeset you using XPATH or anything like that. You can also use something like this:

https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/

Comment: No no no I need to used a pure php not using some javascript

Comment: I posted the wrong link. Updated post with the following url: https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what is your problem?

It's 100% normal that you got an undefined index error.

In your HTML, 2 IDs are defined: 'test' and 'test2'.

Your PHP code finds those two ID and look for an entry inside $data,
however, $data contains only an entry for 'test',
so PHP tells you that there is no entry for 'test2': Notice: Undefined index: test2

That's it :-)

Comment: thats why I'm asking about declaring a value in **test2** if there's no entry on it