# How to create vertical text in phtml

Tags: php

I had a template in HTML with vertical line but when I display code in a phtml file, it's no longer vertical:

So I need to know why and then how to make my code in vertical way

```
<svg width="50" height="300">
            <text x="28" y="150" 
            transform="rotate(-90, 28, 150)" >
            This text is vertical</text>
        </svg>
```

I need to have it like this: [vertical text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMTJ7.png)

(Sorry for adding an image in URL format but I don't have the ability to do it 'autrement' ("an other way")).

Comment: take a look at the css transform effekt "rotate"

Comment: with rotate it worked in html but in phtml it didn't

Comment: Than you apache is not well configurated. Take a look at the explaining of phtml like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11859093/7993505