# How do I get a URL parameter in a PHP template?

Tags: php

Let's say my URL is the following:

```
https://www.example.com/downloads?query=RobinHood
```

In my template (`.phtml` file), I have the following input:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Query for books" name="query">
```

What I want to do is check if the URL parameter called `query` actually exists, and if it does, I want to put it as the value for the input.

How can I do this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: `.phtml`? What PHP version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `.phtml` is an extension used for `php2`, here's what the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/phpfi2.php#getpost) say:

> Any component of the GET data (the data following a '?' in the URL) which is of the form, word=something will define the variable $word to contain the value something. Even if the data is not of this form, it can be accessed with the $argv built-in array

So based on this, `php2` will automatically create variables for the `GET` data:

```
https://www.example.com/downloads?query=RobinHood

$query    // should contain "RobinHood"
$argv[0]  // should contain "query=RobinHood"
```

To check if a variable has been set you can use [IsSet()](https://www.php.net/manual/phpfi2.php#isset) function:

> The IsSet function returns 1 if the given variable is defined, and 0 if it isn't.

```
if( IsSet($query) )
{
    //...
}
```

**Note:** All of the above is purely based on docs. I haven't tested this.

Comment: I really doubt someone's actually using PHP v2 in 2021.

Comment: @ceejayoz Me too, but from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11859122/8202589) and a few other sources it seems to be attributed to php2. I'm not sure if the extension can be used in later versions of PHP and how it behaves.

Comment: I think the more likely explanation is someone's just using `.phtml` either for very very very legacy reasons (old URLs) or an affectation/anachronism.

Comment: @ceejayoz I agree, that's very likely the case. Curious to see what the OP will answer to your question about the version in the comments.

Comment: I guess it is a legacy system actually.

Comment: @darkhorse Yikes!

Answer (score 0):

You can check the query parameter from `$_GET` variable:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Query for books" name="query" <?php echo isset($_GET['query']) ? '"value"="'.$_GET['query'].'"' : '' ?>>
```

Comment: Can you share the whole file?!

Comment: @darkhorse In what *way* does it not work? Do you get an error? Do you see the PHP tags in source code unexecuted?